# Problems with VPN PPTP

Tags: vpn, pptp

I'm having trouble connect to vpn's public pptp, I can not connect smoothly and sail well on the internet about the vpn, so that after a while I can not browse web page no, my syslog file contains following information Property:

```
Mar 4 20:41:41 lubuntupc pppd [3794]: Protocol-Reject is unsupported protocol 0x8d
Mar 4 20:41:41 lubuntupc pppd [3794]: Protocol-Reject is unsupported protocol 0x7a83
Mar 4 20:41:41 lubuntupc pppd [3794]: Protocol-Reject is unsupported protocol 0x497
Mar 4 20:41:41 lubuntupc pppd [3794]: Protocol-Reject is unsupported protocol 0xf3
Mar 4 20:41:41 lubuntupc pppd [3794]: Protocol-Reject is unsupported protocol 0x421b
Mar 4 20:41:41 lubuntupc pppd [3794]: Protocol-Reject is unsupported protocol 0x5628
Mar 4 20:41:41 lubuntupc pppd [3794]: Protocol-Reject is unsupported protocol 0xa9
Mar 4 20:41:42 lubuntupc pppd [3794]: Protocol-Reject is unsupported protocol 0x17
Mar 4 20:41:42 lubuntupc pppd [3794]: Protocol-Reject is unsupported protocol 0x8ef5
Mar 4 20:41:42 lubuntupc pppd [3794]: Protocol-Reject is unsupported protocol 0x8671
Mar 4 20:41:43 lubuntupc pppd [3794]: Protocol-Reject is unsupported protocol 0xf7
```

Would like you guys to help to solve this problem.
Already thank.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever protocols you have selected for negotiation on your end are being denied by the public server on the pptp vpn.

You should contact the VPN provider on this one for the proper client side configurations as it's possible they changed their accepted negotiation protocols.  At this point only the provider can assist you with fixing this.